# Is there documentation available for Google Cloud Dataflow?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow

**Google Cloud Dataflow** has been released in June 2014 (more information in [this blog post](http://googlecloudplatform.blogspot.fr/2014/06/reimagining-developer-productivity-and-data-analytics-in-the-cloud-news-from-google-io.html)), but I can't find any technical documentation on the developers section of the cloud.google.com website: https://cloud.google.com/developers/

Does someone knows where I can find more information, technical documentation about this product?

I'm really interested about how works topology, is it static or dynamic?.. etc..

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Google Cloud Dataflow is now in Alpha stage.  The documentation is now publicly available here:  https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/. Follow the documentation link.

Please note that in Alpha - access to the managed service is limited to invite only.  You can request access via the link above. Use the "Apply for Alpha" button.

The Cloud Dataflow SDK for Java has also been made public & open sourced on GitHub here:  https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowJavaSDK.  Please note that you can download the SDK and run your Dataflow programs locally without having to execute them on the managed service.  Local pipeline execution is a great way to get a feel for the programming model, but understand that the  local execution is not parallelized.

We are also moving support over to StackOverflow. Please use the tag: [google-cloud-dataflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-cloud-dataflow).

Cheers - Eric

Answer (score 2):

Google Cloud Dataflow is currently in private beta. You can apply [here](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1Enq1EKFrujUx2NBBhc_KRGQL6qLvWlT_0Bub4rN3FSs/viewform). Documentation is provided upon approval.